# Must declare the scalar variable "@countprov" error

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

This is my code,could you please help

```
declare @database_id varchar(50);
declare @name varchar(50);

declare Countofprovider cursor for
select database_id ,name
from sys.databases
where name like 'CPM_%stg'
group by name , database_id order by database_id

open Countofprovider

fetch next from Countofprovider
into @database_id, @name

while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin
    --print 'ID : '+ @database_id+' , Name : '+ @name+ ''
    Declare @SQL nvarchar(MAX)

    -- declare @countprov varchar(50);
    SET @sql= '
      declare @countprov int

      select @countprov=count(*) from '+@name+'.dbo.Patients
      where birthdate is null or birthdate = '' or year(birthdate) = 1900

      insert into dbo.countofpaitnets(databse_id,name,countofpatients)
      values('''+@database_id+''','''+@name+''',@countprov)
    '

    exec (@SQL)

    --select count(*) from [CPM_CHE_WAVE3_STG].dbo.patinents where birthdate is null
    --insert into dbo.sampledbkarthi values ('+@database_id+' , '+@name+','+@countprov+')

    fetch next from Countofprovider
    into @database_id, @name, @countprov
end

CLOSE Countofprovider;
DEALLOCATE Countofprovider;
```

When I'm trying to execute it, I'm getting this error:

> Must declare the scalar variable “@countprov” error

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove `@countprov` from the below statement:

```
fetch next from Countofprovider into @database_id,@name,@countprov
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant use `@countprov` in

```
fetch next from Countofprovider into @database_id,@name,@countprov
```

Because There is no `@countprov`.

Create temp table to get `countprov`

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TempTable') IS NOT NULL drop table #TempTable
CREATE TABLE #TempTable (countprov INT)

 SET @sql= '
        declare @countprov int
        select @countprov = Count(*) 
        from '+@name+'.dbo.Patients 
        where birthdate is null or birthdate = '' or year(birthdate) = 1900

       insert into dbo.countofpaitnets(databse_id,name,countofpatients) values('''+@database_id+''','''+@name+''',@countprov)

        INSERT INTO #TempTable
        SELECT @countprov

       '
```

Last step.

```
fetch next from Countofprovider into 
                          @database_id,
                          @name, 
                          (SELECT TOP 1 countprov FROM #TempTable) -- @countprov
```

Answer (score 0):

The second `FETCH` for the `Countofprovider` cursor incorrectly includes `,@countprov`, but **your cursor is only setup to return two columns**.

Looking at the cursor in isolation we should have the following:

```
-- Variables for cursor
DECLARE @name VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @database_id VARCHAR(50)

-- Setup cursor
DECLARE Countofprovider CURSOR FOR
 SELECT database_id, name
   FROM sys.databases
  WHERE name LIKE 'CPM_%stg'
  GROUP BY name, database_id
  ORDER BY database_id

OPEN Countofprovider   

-- Get first result
FETCH NEXT FROM Countofprovider INTO @database_id, @name

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Id: ' + @database_id + ', Name: ' + @name

    -- Iteration logic goes here

    FETCH NEXT FROM Countofprovider INTO @database_id, @name
END

CLOSE Countofprovider;
DEALLOCATE Countofprovider
```

The above will now iterate each result in the cursor, placing  `database_id` and `name` into each of the declared variables `@database_id` and `@name` respectively.

The iteration logic SQL is as follows:

```
Declare @SQL nvarchar(MAX) 

SET @sql= '
    declare @countprov int

    select @countprov=count(*) from '+@name+'.dbo.Patients where birthdate is null or birthdate = '' or year(birthdate) = 1900
    insert into dbo.countofpaitnets(databse_id,name,countofpatients) values('''+@database_id+''','''+@name+''',@countprov)'

exec (@SQL)

-- select count(*) from [CPM_CHE_WAVE3_STG].dbo.patinents where birthdate is null
--insert into dbo.sampledbkarthi values ('+@database_id+' , '+@name+','+@countprov+')
```

So currently the above logic will construct a dynamic query to get a count of patients in a specified database (@name in each iteration), and insert the count into `dbo.countofpaitnets`.